# Подскажите почему на странице перестал работать select плагина jQuery Form Styler

Tags: html, css, jquery, select

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему перестал работать плагин jQuery Form Styler на странице. Вчера еще работа, сегодня - нет. Может опытным взглядом сможете подсказать в чем проблема. 
Вот ссылка на [исходники](https://github.com/monsara/fizzyslim) на github  (там же ссылка и на github page)

Comment: У меня всё работает. Несколько криво сверстанное, но работает: http://icecream.me/41ccc4ecdcc5f1a595320eee776e161e

Может дело в каком-то кеше у вас? Пробовали чистить через ctrl+f5?

Comment: Благодарю. Да, скорей всего, так и было. Уже работает. Буду очень вам благодарен, если опишите, что именно криво сверстано, так как я делаю эту верстку в рамках технического задания на собеседование)